# How to get the text of a menu item with its ID

Tags: visual-prolog

I have an old visual prolog project in which I have to change the text of a menu during runtime.
This is what I've done to change the text:

```
menu_setText(Win, id_menu, NewMenuText)
```

This works fine, however, when I want to enable/disable this menu, the following does not work (meaning the menu item doesn't change its state):

```
menu_Enable(Win, id_menu, b_true)
```

After some search, I found that:

> Under MS-Windows, submenus can not be referred to by a resource identifier. If the menu entry for a submenu, needs to enabled, disabled, checked or have the text changed. it is necessary to use a special versions of the **menu_Enable**, **menu_Check** and **menu_SetText** predicates, which specify the text of the menu entry instead of the constant.
>       `menu_Enable(WinHandle, String, BOOLEAN)`
>       `menu_Check(WinHandle, String, BOOLEAN)`
>       `menu_SetText(WinHandle, String, NewString)`

The weird thing is that in my case, `menu_setText` works just fine with the constant where `menu_Enable` requires the text itself. (yes I tested `menu_Enable` with the initial text of the menu item, but when the text changes then everything breaks)

**Here comes my question:**

> How can I enable/disable a menu when I know its ID but not its name ?
>   If not possible directly, how can I get the current name of a menu when I know its ID ?

In case this helps, this project is opened and compiled with VIP52 (since before the year 2001).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround that solves my problem, but I'm still not really satisfied, so if anyone comes up with a better answer, I'll take it !

I declared:

```
txt_menu(menu_tag,string)
```

And then called:

```
txt_menu(id_menu, MenuText),
menu_setText(Win, MenuText, NewText),
retractAll(txt_menu(id_menu,_)),
assert(txt_menu(id_menu,NewText)),
menu_Update(Win)
```

whenever I have to change the text of a menu item, and this can easily be transformed into a `menu_setTextById` predicate as such:

```
menu_setTextById(Win, MenuId, NewText):-
    txt_menu(MenuId, MenuText),
    menu_setText(Win, MenuText, NewText),
    retractAll(txt_menu(MenuId,_)),
    assert(txt_menu(MenuId, NewText)),
    menu_Update(Win).
```

with the usage:

```
menu_setTextById(Win, id_menu, "My new text menu").
```

Noted that if I ever have the need to have several windows with menus, I'll have to add the Window Id to my `txt_menu` clause.

---

The main problem with this workaround is that I can't use `&` in the new text menu because if my menu has "&Menu" as text (meaning that `M` will be underlined), then trying to use `menu_setText(Win,"&Menu","New Menu")` will break because "&Menu" is not found.

So I'd need to remove any ampersand from the string before trying to use it in such predicates.